# Functions of State and Clairaut's Theorem

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, potential, differentiation

In deriving the conditions for a function $f(x,y)$ to be a function of state, we end up finding out that it needs to satisfy Clairaut's Theorem:
$$
f_{xy} = f_{yx}
$$
Where
$$
df = F_1 dx + F_2dy
$$
and
$$
\vec{F} = \nabla f (x,y)
$$
Where $x$ and $y$ are themselves functions of state. My question is this (I don't know if this is too vague) is this equation talking more about the orthogonality of the parameters $x$ and $y$ than about the scalar function $f$ itself, considering that most scalar functions follow Clairaut's Theorem anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of orthogonality here because there is no inner product. However,

> most scalar functions follow Clairaut's Theorem anyway

That is precisely the point. A function of state is just that - a function of the state variables of the system. If you can put it in a form like $f(T,V,N)$ for example, then it's already a function of state.

---

The main idea here is that in thermodynamics, we are often encounter expressions involving *infinitesimal changes* in a function rather than an explicit expression for the function itself.  That is, we encounter things like
$$\mathrm df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\ \mathrm dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \ \mathrm dy$$

However, we also encounter expressions like
$$w = \alpha(x,y) \ \mathrm dx + \beta(x,y)\ \mathrm dy$$

It is natural to ask, given such a $w$, whether there exists some function $f$ such that $w = \mathrm df$. In particular, if such a function exists then it implies that

$$\int_A^B w = f(B)-f(A)$$
i.e. that the integral of $w$ between two points (states, in this context) depends only on the endpoints and not on the path taken between them.

The point of referencing Clairaut's theorem is that if such an $f$ exists (and is sufficiently smooth), then we **must** have that
$$\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}$$

On the other hand, if $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}$, it follows that there is no such function $f$. In such cases we say that $w$ is an "inexact differential," and its integral between two points is path-dependent.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!